# Laravel 5.2 Custom Authentication

Tags: php, laravel, authentication, laravel-5

I'm using a table named `admins` to store `name|email|password|contact` of all the admins instead of the built in users table provided by Laravel and my login/logout controller code is given below.

It's not working perfectly and not even throwing any error. Do I need to configure config/auth.php file for this? If I need to then what should it look like? And suppose I have another table for managers and they have `name|email|password|contact`like admins. How can I configure them?

AdminloginController:

```
<?php

namespace App\Http\Controllers;


use App\Model\Admin;
use Illuminate\Database\QueryException;
use Illuminate\Http\Request;
use App\Http\Requests;
use Illuminate\Support\Facades\Auth;
use Illuminate\Support\Facades\Validator;

class AdminLoginController extends Controller
{
    public function postLogin(Request $request){
        if(Auth::attempt(['email'=> $request->email,'password'=> $request->password])){
            return redirect('/AdminPanel');
        }
        return redirect()->back();
    }
    public function getLogout(Request $request){
        Auth::logout();
        return redirect('/');
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you have multiple tables with same columns you should rather not create many tables. It would be better if you use one table (might be default `users`) and for each user set also role (either `admin` or `manager`). It might not make any point to create multiple users tables. Consider also that in future you might need also different type of managers etc. and you will finally have a few users table instead of one.

You should really consider this when you don't have more tables yet to not have do many changes in your code in future.